# How can I make a switch case based on a boolean? [specifically based on char.isLetterOrDigit()]

Tags: java, switch-statement

My assignment is to code & use the Shunting Yard algorithm in Java. I've seen how I can implement it using if/else statements, but the snippet of pseudocode provided by my professor uses switch cases. What's written is this:

```
for (each character ch in the infix expr){
  switch (ch) {
    case operand:
      break;
    case '(':
      break;
    case ')':
      break;
    case operator:
      break;
```

I know that I can use the boolean isLetterOrDigit() to determine whether "ch" is an operand, but I don't know how to convert that into something I can apply to the case. Under "operator" I've just got it written out as

```
switch (ch) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
      break;
```

But I'm wondering if that could also be simplified? Or should I just stick to if/else?

Comment: You can make a string inside the for loop and add equation character by character to the string and close the string after it reaches an operator that is, in the switch statement

Comment: Probably should just stick to `if`/`else`. No need to implement a switch statement for booleans when if/else literally does exactly that. Don't think Java supports pattern-matching switches, unfortunately, which would be more the solution you're looking for.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Java 17 supports pattern-matching switches in preview, see [JEP 406: Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406)